# How do I unsubscribe from a Firestore listener in React-Native?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

How do I unsubscribe from a Firestore listener in React-Native? I have a function where I am fetching and listening to changes in Firestore:

```
_fetchPatientsList() {
        var query = firestore().collection('Collection').doc().collection('public');
        query = query.where('act', '==', 1);
        query = query.where('city', '==', this.state.selected_city);
        query = query.orderBy('update_time', 'desc');
        query = query.limit(10);

        query.onSnapshot({
            error: (e) => this.setState({ errorMessage: e, refreshingPatients: false }),
            next: (querySnapshot) => {
                ///do something      
            },
        });
 }
```

And I would like to unsubscribe when I log out:

```
    _logOutHandler = () => {
    auth()
        .signOut()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('User signed out!')
        });
    let unsub = firestore().collection('Collection').doc().collection('public').onSnapshot(() => {
    });

    // Stop listening for changes
    unsub();
}
```

Is this the proper way of doing it?

Comment: Does the code work the way you expect?  If not, could you edit the question to explain what exactly it's doing that's different than what you want?

Comment: @DougStevenson I cant test it at the moment but was just wondering if that's the way I should do it or not as the documentation doesn't give much details and its confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to save a listener reference `const unsubRef = query.onSnapshot`

use the reference, example:

```js
const unsubRef = query.onSnapshot({
 error: (e) => this.setState({ errorMessage: e, refreshingPatients: false }),
 next: (querySnapshot) => {
   ///do something      
 },
});

//just make it to unsubscribe
unsubRef();
```

to stop listener on other function, you can make this:

```js
import from ....

//variables
let unsubRef;


// function to stop listener
stopListener = (unsubRef) => {
   unsubRef();
};

//save the reference for this query
unsubRef = query.onSnapshot({
            error: (e) => this.setState({ errorMessage: e, refreshingPatients: false }),
            next: (querySnapshot) => {
                ///do something      
            },
        });


//other function you want cancel listener
otherFunc = async() => {
   // some code

   //stop the listener
   await this.stopListener(unsubRef);
   //signout code
};
```

you can see more details here:
https://rnfirebase.io/firestore/usage#realtime-changes
or
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#detach_a_listener

Comment: I have the listener in another function and I want to unsubscribe from another function.

Comment: should I call exactly the same reference?

Comment: yep, it's like an ID to access this listener for that query.

Comment: great! Thanks, I did it like that. Btw any idea how to clear State when logging out?

Comment: yes, you can use `async`, `await`. await for unsubscribe, and then log out. reverse the order of your signout function, stop the listener first and then log out, see the new edit with async await

Comment: Thanks, but what I was asking is : I have many variables set in this.State which I would like to clear when logging out, how can I do that? Note: I have everything in one class.

Comment: what do you mean, "clear"? when logging out, is your component disassembled?
if yes, you don't need to clear states

Comment: how is a component disassembled? That's only done when componentWillUnmount() is triggered. What if user logs out but keeps the app opened? The state is not reset yet!

Comment: normally when the logout occurs, the user is redirected to another page, and this already causes the component to be disassembled, but the user remains in the application, I don't know how to clear the states ;(